# Have the Taliban held/allowed any multi-candidate elections since coming to power?

Tags: election, afghanistan, local-government, taliban

Interestingly, the Taliban of 2022 [appear](https://thediplomat.com/2022/04/the-peculiar-case-of-elections-under-the-taliban/) to hold some limited local elections, although the example given there involved open (one vote per household) voting and (more importantly) one candidate, at least in that example.

Are there examples of the Taliban allowing/holding multi-candidate (local) elections? And if so, for what kind of posts?